# How can i change viewModel dynamically if i have one viewModel for each user control

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In main window this is my data context

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator}, Path=MainVM}"
```

---

and this is my grid binding

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource ChatContentStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

and that's how i switch them

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LoginTemplate">
    <views:LoginView/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ChatTemplate">
    <views:ChatView/>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="ChatContentStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LoginTemplate}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UserMode}" Value="{x:Static enums:UserModes.Chat}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ChatTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I want to change the viewModel exact like I'm changing the view

Comment: Make your ContentControl bind against a property that provides either the login viewmodel or the chat viewmodel. Set the DataType for each DataTemplate to the respective viewmodel type. (The style trigger then would have no use anymore and can be deleted.) Depending on user action or program logic, swap the login/chat viewmodel in that property...

Comment: MVVM rule: Each View has exactly one ViewModel which represents an abstraction of that View.

Comment: @SirRufo I would say, that View is a representation of ViewModel

Comment: @Rekshino Yes of course, the View is the concrete representation of the ViewModel, which is an abstraction of the View

Comment: @SirRufo ..representation of VieModel or it's part, I would say. :)